# Pentaho: Is there a way to add Date calendar picker as parameter in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to create a report with multiple parameters using the Pentaho Report Designer. One of the parameters as input is Date. Is there any way we can use a date picker (picture attached) instead of drop down or single value list in the report designer. I am using the Pentaho Community Edition.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you will add new parameter and select the type as date , it will automatically adds this component.